# Perl вставить знак градуса и минуты в строку

Tags: perl

Пытаюсь вставить знак градуса в строку, но ничего из этого не выходить. Подскажите как это можно реализовать в Perl?

Comment: А куда эта строка "выводится" ?

Comment: Ну это вообще внутренние скрипты. Есть скрипт шаблона оповещения, туда вставляются данные по координатам, взятые из базы. Мне надо допилить, чтобы грамотный формат был.

Comment: Ну например `$_="\x{0B0}";` отлично в переменную градус кладет. Но при выводе этой строки куда либо файловый дескриптор вывода разумеется должен быть в режиме UTF8, что бы выводились два байта C2 B0, а не просто B0. Кроме того символ градуса можно спокойно написать прямо в тексте программы (программа разумеется должна быть с `use utf8`)

Comment: Понятно, ответ придется вытягивать. Если скрипты выводят в консоль и она нормально понимает utf-8 (обычно это так и есть, но некоторые любят в koi-8), то просто скопируйте его и вставьте себе в скрипт. Вот он `°`. (да,  редактор также должен в utf-8 редактировать).

Если же это не так - ищите для Вашей кодировки этот символ.

Comment: Как написать знак градуса я понимаю. Теперь вопрос, который задал первый комментирующий стал более понятен. Сейчас вывожу в консоль для проверки. Там абракадабра. А в конечном итоге это все отправляется по email и в веб-интерфейсе.

Comment: Ну для консоли не забывайте давать `use utf8;` `binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');` это конечно если у вас консоль в UTF8

Comment: В вебинтерфейсе же символ вообще лучше закодировать как `&#176;` или `&deg;` что бы браузер точно понял. Ну и кодировка страницы отдаваемая web-сервером должна быть UTF8. Для почты ... там свои способы кодирования

Comment: Благодарю всех за помощь. Попробую сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с непосредственным добавлением символа градуса:

```
perl -E 'say "100°C"'
100°C
```

Вариант с добавлением кода символа градуса:

```
perl -E 'use open ":std", ":encoding(utf8)"; say "100\x{0b0}C"'
100°C
```